# Regex for input is failing on every other keystroke - testing for Hangul chars + numerics + up to 3 roman chars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am testing a user input on each keystroke to make sure that the input rules are enforced. For some reason when typing in the input it takes two keystrokes to input anything. I'm not sure if it's the regex or my setup that is failing.

Regex expected results:

```
// Should pass
보령남로 162
서울특별시 은평구 증산동 증산로9길 13 rrt
도계읍 문의재로 13417931

// Should fail on 4th roman char
a서울a특별시aa
강원도 12345 abcd
```

Here is the regex I'm currently using:

```js
export const hangulAndNumbersAndThreeRomansRegex = 
  /^[\u3131-\uD79D0-9\s]*([a-z][\u3131-\uD79D0-9\s]*){0,3}$/gi;
```

Here is the onChange handler in the Input component that is using the regex:

```js
// inputPattern is the regex from above
const onChange = (e) => {
  if (typeof inputPattern === 'object') {
    // this is reached on every keystroke

    if (inputPattern.test(e.target.value)) {
      // only reaches here on every other keystroke
      inputOnChange(e);
    }

  } else {
    inputOnChange(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you able to add a `console.log(typeof inputPattern);` as the first line of `onChange` to confirm you're getting the expected result?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs yes, that first check passes each time

Comment: I guess I'll head on down the chain then.. if you console log `inputPattern.test(e.target.value)` before the if statement for the test, is that giving a consistent result as well?

Comment: Determining CJK character based on "single keystrokes" might be next to impossible, because those character sets consist of `16-bit` encoding as apposed to `8-bit` (see [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters#Encoding)). For instance, `keydown` of `R` key would register when typing `ㄱ` character, but `change` event might not trigger until the full syllable is entered, because it can be any syllable starting with `ㄱ` consonant—e.g.  `가` `갑` `값` `궳`, or myriad other possibilities.

Comment: @JohnDetlefs That one does not work. Doing it in a console log fails for the log, but then the onChange function works each time.

Comment: @BumhanYu That's really good to know. I didn't realize it got down to that level. I'm guessing the behavior I described in my comment above is happening because of what you're saying. I think I will try moving the logic to a higher level in the component tree to see if that helps. Maybe it will still have the same effect...

Comment: Because of the conjoining nature of Korean writing system, a single keystroke detection would not work. See [this Korean Unicode FAQ article](https://www.unicode.org/faq/korean.html) for reference. In your example, for instance, "보령남도" is _not_ keyed in **4** strokes but **10**.